# How do I pass the argument of a template to another template inside the first

Tags: c++, class, templates

I am not sure how to word this but basically what I am trying to do is have a template class that takes as it's template parameter one or two types that are then used to define pointers to another class that is also a template. I will try to demonstrate what I want to do in the code below.

```
template <typename A> class Alpha{
   public:
   A first;
};
template <typename B> class Beta{
   public:
   B second;
};
template <typename C,typename D> class Group{
   public:
   //I am pretty sure this is not how you do a constructor for a template.
   Group(Alpha<C>* a,Beta<D>* b){
      one = a;
      two = b;
   }

   Alpha<C> * one;
   Beta<D> * two;

};

Alpha<int> a;
Beta<char> b;
Group<int,char> g(&a,&b);
```

This however does not work. I am sure it comes from my lack of understanding the finer points of c++ templates. Any input would be very helpful

**EDIT: Disregard that this works perfectly.**

In my sleep deprived state I some how typed it up correctly for the question while I was missing a key piece of code in the actual alpha Class implementation.

**EDIT2: I have found the true root of my problem**

It would seem that I overlooked the fact that separating Template classes into the usual .h/.cpp file combos does not behave the same as it does with normal classes.

Comment: "does not work" meaning exactly what?

Comment: Did you try it? the code looks fine.

Comment: It compiles? What doesn't work. Edit - actually using it with some debug output works as expected.

Comment: Ah I see The error of my ways the actual code was slightly different than what I typed in here. That's what I get for trying to ask questions at 2 in the morning. Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, but you could encounter some problems:

```
Group<int,char>* g = NULL;
{
   Alpha<int> a;
   Beta<char> b;
   g = new Group<int,char>(&a,&b);
}
//g is no longer correct here
```

This happens because `a` and `b` are only in scope until the closing `}`. But `g` still contains pointers to them. That's why I suggest you only use pointers when you really know how they work. In this case, smart pointers would also be a good choice.

Comment: Yes I recognize that and in the actual implementation I am passing actual pointers to the Group not just passing the address of two local instances.